# Integral extension inside a polynomial ring over a field

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a field and $D = K[X]$. I need to show that if $f\in D$ is non constant, then the extension of rings $K[f]\subset D$ is integral, and if $A$ is a subring of $D$ which contains $K$ and has Krull dimension $1$, then $A$ is a finitely generated $K$-algebra.

Thank you in any advance.

Comment: Uh? You wrote " if f is in D but not in D..." ??

Comment: the question was edited, I think its possible reopen this now... Thank you...@DonAntonio, @Clayton,

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can assume wlog that $f$ is monic. Now you can write down explicitly a polynomial which shows that $X$ is integral over $K[f]$. etc.

Comment: For the second part of your question can find an answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45690/must-k-subalgebra-of-kx-be-finitely-generated).